# Google Analytics connection with python

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics

I am struggling to connect GA with python by using google2pandas. My error is conn is not defined. I have j.son file and GA ID. Where do i need to save my j.son file? how to get token file .dat?

Answer (score 0):

Google2Pandas has a nice documentation on install and use that answer your questions: https://github.com/panalysis/Google2Pandas

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have installed google2pandas and import into python and i have created json from google API. Where do i need to save my j.son file? how to get token file .dat? Can you please help me?